# Is there a better way to use multiple OR in dict comprehension?

Tags: python

```
x = {'a': (2, 3), 'b': (4, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'd': (1, 0), 'e': (2, 0)} 
x = {
    k: v
    for k, v in x.items()
    if (v[0] >= 2 and v[1] >= 0) or (v[0] >= 1 and v[1] > 1)
}
print(x)
```

In the 'if' block, I have a lot of logical 'or' enclosed with parenthesis. Is there better way to express it in dict comprehension?

Also, I can omit the () in the 'if' statement to make it more consise. Right?

Comment: *Right?* No, that's incorrect. Associativity!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Huh? `and` has higher precedence.

Comment: for a systematic approach you could evaluate each comparison individually to get groups, one for `v0` and for `v1`,  make a pairing with `zip` and apply `and`, apply `any`

Comment: Your example code does not have multiple `or` operators. Please show us an example that actually exhibits the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack the tuple. Keep the parentheses, even though you can technically get away with it; [`and` has a higher precedence than `or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html), but not everyone knows that and this makes it more readable:

```py
x = {k: (fst, snd) for k, (fst, snd) in x.items() if (fst >= 2 and snd >= 0) or (fst >= 1 and snd > 1)}
```

This outputs:

```py
{'a': (2, 3), 'b': (4, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'e': (2, 0)}
```

Comment: So you have to use a lot of 'or' if there are multiple possibilities?

Comment: For two, this is probably the best you're going to get. How many conditions do you actually have?

Comment: Also, do the tuples only contain integers?

Comment: @marlon: If you have many possibilities and there is no sane simplification of the logic, yep, you gotta use a lot of `or`s. Since it seems like you can't even guarantee positive values, I don't see any obvious means of simplifying this. Best you could do here would be something like `if any(fst >= fstlvl and snd >= sndlvl for fstlvl, sndlvl in ((2, 0), (1, 2)))` where expanding the set of things to check only involves adding additional two-`tuple`s to check against, but it's not really any cleaner (and it's longer for just the two).

Comment: I have about 5 possibilities.

Comment: I would do what @ShadowRanger suggested in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> In the 'if' block, I have a lot of logical 'or' enclosed with parenthesis. Is there better way to express it in dict comprehension?

No. Your both "main" conditions have one constraint that is a superset of the same constraint of the other side, and one that is incompatible.

Three boolean operators is the minimum you can do.

Comment: Um, both of these produce `True`, Unless I'm missing something? `and` has a higher precedence than `or`

Comment: Not according to my interpreter.

Comment: ah and having a higher precedence, darn. Then all I can *recommend* is keeping the parentheses anyways, because they do make the expression clearer to read.

Comment: yep, precisely for this very common case!

Comment: So 'and' has higher precedence?

Comment: Yes, `and` has higher precedence. The fact that multiple answerers initially got this wrong should convince you that most people don't know this fact off the top of their head, and you should write complex conditions with that in mind.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark That is my impression, 'and' always has higher precedunce. So I can remove the () part for each OR

Comment: You _can_, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @marlon yeah, removing these parenthesis saves a few bytes of the source code size, which cost you literally nothing, and makes everything harder to read. Don't do it. It's not even making your code any faster.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write a function that checks for whether or not you want to include the item:

```
def my_filter(tup):
    if tup[0] >= 2 and tup[1] >= 0:
        return True
    else: #Chain whatever you want as elif
        return tup[0] >= 1 and tup[1] > 1


x = {'a': (2, 3), 'b': (4, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'd': (1, 0), 'e': (2, 0)} 
y = {
    k: v
    for k, v in x.items()
    if my_filter(v)
}
print(y)
```

Or you could wrap both conditions with `any`:

```
z = {
    k: v
    for k, v in x.items()
    if any(
        [v[0] >= 2 and v[1] >= 0,
         v[0] >= 1 and v[1] > 1]
    )
}
print(z)
```

Both of these will output:

```
{'a': (2, 3), 'b': (4, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'e': (2, 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a bit bad-posed since expect to deal with an uncountable many `or`s is independent of the comprehension-form.

My suggestion is to use a *systematic approach to deal with a chain of (irreducible) `or` conjunctions* based on an auxiliary function.

General idea: form two groups wrt the index of the values of the dictionary, i.e. `v0`, `v1`, together with an own collection of unitary comparison operators ( for short UCO). Then evaluate each group with the proper UCO, apply a termwise `and` to the "product" of both groups and finally reduce with an `any`.

The key step is hence the construction of the unitary comparison operators UCO. It depends on `methodcaller`.
Notice that are some implicit data which are very important because are **invariant** of the iterations: the values that you use to make the comparison. These will be classified with `dict` as following:

- `lb`:   lower bound
- `lbe`:  lower bound also equal to it
- `ub`:   upper bound
- `ube`:  upper bound also equal to it
- `neq`:  not equal to
- `eq`:   equal to
  and used with a mapper which assigns the corresponding name name of the method.
  It is not mandatory but could avoid confusions with the order operators, here an example:

```
lb = 4

2 > lb                 # binary inequality         greater than
int(lb).__lt__(2)      # unitary inequality (UCO)  less than
```

To deal with the invariance of boundaries I used a decorator (not mandatory).

Here my solution:

```
from operator import methodcaller, __and__


def systematic_comparison(v0_boundaries, v1_boundaries):
    # v0_boundaries, v1_boundaries: both tuple of dictionaries, ({2: 'lbe'}, {1: 'lbe'})
    def __systematic_comparison(v0, v1):
        # mapper boundary type - order relation
        mapper = {'lb': '__gt__', 'lbe': '__ge__', 'ub': '__lt__', 'ube': '__le__', 'ne': '__ne__', 'eq': '__eq__'}

        # make unitary comparison operators
        v0_comparisons = []
        for d in v0_boundaries:
            k, v = tuple(d.items())[0]
            v0_comparisons.append(methodcaller(mapper[v], k))
        v1_comparisons = []
        for d in v1_boundaries:
            k, v = tuple(d.items())[0]
            v1_comparisons.append(methodcaller(mapper[v], k))

        # evaluate unitary comparisons operator
        v0_checks = [comp(v0) for comp in v0_comparisons]
        v1_checks = [comp(v1) for comp in v1_comparisons]

        # pairwise-and separated by or
        return any(map(__and__, v0_checks, v1_checks))

    return __systematic_comparison


x = {'a': (2, 3), 'b': (4, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'd': (1, 0), 'e': (2, 0)}
x = {
    k: (v0, v1)
    for k, (v0, v1) in x.items()
    if systematic_comparison(v0_boundaries=({2: 'lbe'}, {1: 'lbe'}), v1_boundaries=({0: 'lbe'}, {1: 'lb'}))(v0, v1)
}
print(x)
#{'a': (2, 3), 'b': (4, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'e': (2, 0)}
```

The code can be made a bit more compact like this:

```
def systematic_comparison(v0_boundaries, v1_boundaries):
    # v0_boundaries, v1_boundaries: both tuple of dictionaries, ({2: 'lbe'}, {1: 'lbe'})
    def __systematic_comparison(v0, v1):
        # mapper boundary type - order relation
        mapper = {'lb': '__gt__', 'lbe': '__ge__', 'ub': '__lt__', 'ube': '__le__', 'ne': '__ne__', 'eq': '__eq__'}

        # make unitary comparison operators
        v_comparisons = []
        for d in v0_boundaries + v1_boundaries: # merge together -> size double
            k, v = tuple(d.items())[0]
            v_comparisons.append(methodcaller(mapper[v], k))
        
        # size of half list of v_comparisons
        n = len(v0_boundaries)

        # groupwise comparison and pairwise-and separated by or
        return any(map(__and__, [comp(v0) for comp in v_comparisons[:n]], [comp(v1) for comp in v_comparisons[n:]]))

    return __systematic_comparison
```

Here an example of the syntax with 3 or more conditions:

```
v0_boundaries = ({2: 'lbe'}, {1: 'lbe'}, {8: 'ne'}, ...)
v1_boundaries = ({0: 'lbe'}, {1: 'lb'}, {10: 'eq'}, ...)

systematic_comparison(v0_boundaries, v1_boundaries)
```

Comment: What benefit does this offer? This seems like a lot of unnecessary/extra computation?

Comment: @0x263A What would happen if you had 5, 10, or more conditions to check? Will you write them all by hand? The OP mentioned in a comment that has 5 and the title suggests a problem when dealing with _mutiple `or`s_